# Add the Top border if the the cell is not empty

Tags: vba, excel

This is adding the top border.

```
Sub getBorders()
Dim rngToChange As Range
Dim C As Range
Set rngToChange = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:C10")

For Each C In rngToChange
    If C <> "" Then
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        C.Borders.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    Else
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone

    End If

Next
End Sub
```

However, in the last row, the bottom border is deleted. How to modify the loop?

[image]

Comment: what is your starting situation? As far as I can tell it doesn't touch the bottom border of row 10. So if there was a border there in the first place, it should still be there. Or do you by "deleting" actually mean "not adding"?

Comment: At starting situation the bottom border is there, but after running the above code, it disapperred

Comment: and you're using the exact same code and the exact same setup as the one in your picture? Because on my machine it's working just fine... @Jordan 's answer should work, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: It works fine if the last row is equal to 10. I would like to modify if i don't know the range ends

Comment: The problem maybe in       Set rngToChange = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:C10")
If the end range is equal to the last non empty cell, the works fine. If the end range is unknow, it make the bottom border disappear like above img

Comment: that's actually a different question altogether... Depending on your exact requirements, you can for example use the Selection property or ask the user to enter the range in an InputBox

Answer (score 1):

You could check if 'C' is in the last row and then apply a bottom border if the condition is met:

```
Sub getBorders()
Dim rngToChange As Range
Dim C As Range
Set rngToChange = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:C10")

For Each C In rngToChange
    If C <> "" Then
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        C.Borders.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    Else
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
    'If you always know the end of your range simply replace 10 with the end row
    If C.Row = 10 Then  
        C.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        C.Borders.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End if
Next
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could replace the 10 with something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlup).Row` if you don't know where the range ends but want to select the last non-empty cell in column B.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
  Sub getBorders()
     Dim rngToChange As Range
     Dim C As Range
     Set rngToChange = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:C10")

    For Each C In rngToChange
       If C <> "" Then
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        C.Borders.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      Else
     If C = "B10" Or C = "C10" Then
       Else
        C.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        C.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
     End If
End If

 Next
 End Sub
```